# Check if function body references symbols that are not arguments (formals)

Tags: r, function, unit-testing

I was implementing a long function which takes many arguments and realised that the function body referenced a variable (symbol) which was not an argument (i.e. not a formal contained in the call signature) but the function was failing silently since the variable was present in the global environment. This is of course a common problem for beginners, but also more experienced users on occasion.

**Is there a way, either programmatically or via a tool available in a popular UI (e.g. RStudio) to quickly check the modularity of functions?**

Of course one can implement unit tests and in general be careful when writing scripts but tests are overkill for functions used only for parts of brief projects and a tool as described would be useful when writing longer / more complicated scripts.

I have extracted out the core idea in the following snippet where the question is effectively: How can the presence of `z` in the function body of `add_three_numbers` be quickly, easily and ideally automatically identified?

```r
z <- 2

add_three_numbers <- function(x, y) {
  x + y + z
}

add_three_numbers(1, 2)
```

For example, I imagined a function that parses the function body and differences a set of the symbols found therein with the list of symbols making up the formal arguments of that function if doing this programmatically, or else a function in RStudio that somehow achieves the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R CMD check` will do this for you if your code is in a package. If you're not using a package, you should be. The test uses `codetools::findGlobals`.  For example,

```r
add_three_numbers <- function(x, y) {
  x + y + z
}

codetools::findGlobals(add_three_numbers, merge = FALSE)
#> $functions
#> [1] "{" "+"
#> 
#> $variables
#> [1] "z"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>